# Debugging git network issues

Tags: git, macos, debugging, networking, git-push

Is there a way to see what’s going on at network level when I do a `git push`?
I would prefer some kind of command line utility to see what's happening. The protocol is `ssh`. Using `GIT_TRACE=1` doesn't give me much info

Answer (score 0):

To check network traffic I would suggest running Wireshark, or TShark.
Simply add a filter to only see what you want, in this case

```
tcp.dstport==22
```

Now you can see all SSH traffic

Comment: but how do I combine this with a git push?

Comment: just run Wireshark and while the program is open and capturing do your git push

Answer (score 0):

Better way to run tcpdump with `host`key:

`tcpdump -i any host 1.1.1.1`

Comment: but how do I combine this with a git push?

Comment: You will just check connectivity between client and server